# Specify ivy configuration in gradle dependency

Tags: groovy, gradle, ivy

I want to resolve dependencies from ivy repository but I don't know how to specify ivy configuration for it. I found that I should do it in this way:

```
myconf group: 'com.eu', module:'MyModule', version:'1.0.0', configuration: 'ivyconf'
```

but it doesn't work. When I run `gradle dependencies` command gradle returns this error:

```
Could not create a dependency using notation: {group=com.eu, module=MyModule, version=1.0.0, configuration=ivyconf}
```

My build doesn't use plugins. I want to download dependencies in simple build which should create product from downloaded dependencies.

Build looks like this:

```
group = 'com.eu'
version = '0.9a'

configurations {
    myconf
}

repositories {
    ivy  {
        url 'http://ivyrepo.local/ivyrep/shared'
        layout "pattern", {
            artifact "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact].[ext]"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    myconf group: 'com.eu', module:'MyModule', version:'1.0.0', configuration: 'ivyconf'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `module`, it has to be `name`. (see "49.4. How to declare your dependencies" in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html)). The declared configuration (`myConf`) must match the configuration used in the `dependencies` block (`installer`).

Comment: Thanks! Can you also aswer if it possible to declare dependency in a short way 'com.eu:MyModule:1.0.0:<CONF_NAME>' ?

Comment: To specify a configuration explicitly (rather than going with `default`), you'll have to use the long notation.